# Accessing the top bar in Android Google docs without scrolling to top

Tags: google-drive

When editing a Google document on Android using the Google Drive app, there is a bar which contains a number of touch buttons for formatting, sharing, comments, etc.

However this bar only seems to display by default when at the very top of the document, or after scrolling up (away from the thing I am editing), which becomes a pain as a document gets larger. Is there some way to access these options from anywhere within the document?

[image: Screenshot of bar from phone]